# Saving Checked radio buttons in safecracker

Tags: safecracker

I have created a safecracker form that has some fields that with show / hide depending on the previous filed selection.
For example:

```
 <label
    for="med">Are you currently taking any prescribed medication?:</label>
    <label><input
    type="radio" name="med" value="Yes"{checked} id="med2"  />&nbsp;Yes</label><label><input
    type="radio" name="med" value="No"{checked} id="med1"  />&nbsp;No</label>

    <br>{clear}<br>
<div id="med">
     <label for="medication" class="required">Please detail:</label>    {field:medication}<br></div>
```

This code will show the {field:medication} if the yes radio button is selected.
I can't use the normal code provided in the safecracker example as each field option needs to have a different id for the jquery action.

Unfortunately the {checked} code does not save the radio option when the form is saved. 
I'd appreciate any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<input type="radio" name="my_field" value="Yes"{if med == 'Yes'}Checked{/if} />
<input type="radio" name="my_field" value="No"{if med == 'No'}Checked{/if} />
```

If you get problems saving a 'required' field, then try adding hidden inputs:

```
<input name="my_field" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Comment: This helped me today.. Thanks for the reminder :D

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment rather than an answer but I can post better code examples here. So the example for using [custom fields](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#custom-fields) looks like:

```
  {if radio}
            {options}
                    <label class="checkbox">{option_value}
                            <input type="radio" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
                    </label>
            {/options}
    {/if}
```

That includes IDs. Why can't you use that code?

Comment: Does the id on the example not output the same for both values? I need a different id for each value.

Comment: In that case you could do something like `id="{field_name}_{option_value}"`.